# Autotrack.js plugin urlChangeTracker does not work with single page Shiny application

Tags: javascript, r, google-analytics, shiny

I am trying to use the urlChangeTracker for tracking the use of an R shiny application hosted on in a linux virtual machine in the cloud. The shiny application is basically a single page application in the form of a dashboard containing several tabs. I have build the shiny application in such a way that for every tab the url of the website is changed, so that (in theory) I can use the urlChangeTracker plugin to track which tabs users are viewing.

My tracking code snippet looks like this:

```
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker')

ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js"></script>
<script async src="path/to/autotrack.js"></script>
```

I did not install autotrack.js with npm but I have downloaded the file from the autotrack github repository and saved it in an accesible directory on the linux server. I have also checked whether the autotrack.js file is available by visiting myWebsite.com/autotrack.js, and it was available as such:

```
(function(){var g,aa="function"==typeof Object.defineProperties?Object.defineProperty:function(a,b,c){if(c.get||c.set)throw new TypeError("ES3 does not support getters and setters.");a!=Array.prototype&&a!=Object.prototype&&(a[b]=c.value)},k="undefined"!=typeof window&&window===this?this:"undefined"!=typeof global&&null!=global?global:this;function l(){l=function(){};k.Symbol||(k.Symbol=ba)}var ca=0;function ba(a){return"jscomp_symbol_"+(a||"")+ca++}
function m(){l();var a=k.Symbol.iterator;a||(a=k.Symbol.iterator=k.Symbol("iterator"));"function"!=typeof Array.prototype[a]&&aa(Array.prototype,a,{configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:function(){return da(this)}});m=function(){}}function da(a){var b=0;return ea(function(){return b<a.length?{done:!1,value:a[b++]}:{done:!0}})}function ea(a){m();a={next:a};a[k.S 
[...]
```

The analytics_debug.js report looks as follows:

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
analytics_debug.js:16 No plugin url set for "urlChangeTracker".
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "cleanUrlTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "eventTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "impressionTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "maxScrollTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "mediaQueryTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "outboundFormTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "outboundLinkTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "pageVisibilityTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "socialWidgetTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "urlChangeTracker", Function)
analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("create", "UA-XXXXX-Y", "auto")
analytics_debug.js:16 Creating new tracker: t0
analytics_debug.js:16 Auto cookieDomain found: "example.com"
analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("require", "urlChangeTracker")
analytics_debug.js:16 Plugin "urlChangeTracker" intialized on tracker "t0".
analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:16 Setting throttling cookie: "_gat"
analytics_debug.js:16 
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j79d&a=1855665599&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftab1%2tab2%2F&ul=nl-nl&de=UTF-8&dt=example%20tab3%20tab4&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1140x901&je=0&_u=QCCAAEAD~&jid=2127417377&gjid=1964178890&cid=428550628.1567514178&tid=UA-55220421-10&_gid=1087991776.1567514178&_r=1&_av=2.4.1&_au=100&did=i5iSjo&z=198028291


analytics_debug.js:16 <unknown>        (&did)  i5iSjo
analytics_debug.js:16 _j1              (&jid)  2127417377
analytics_debug.js:16 _j2              (&gjid) 1964178890
analytics_debug.js:16 adSenseId        (&a)    1855665599
analytics_debug.js:16 apiVersion       (&v)    1
analytics_debug.js:16 clientId         (&cid)  428550628.1567514178
analytics_debug.js:16 encoding         (&de)   UTF-8
analytics_debug.js:16 hitType          (&t)    pageview
analytics_debug.js:16 javaEnabled      (&je)   0
analytics_debug.js:16 language         (&ul)   nl-nl
analytics_debug.js:16 location         (&dl)   https://example.com/
analytics_debug.js:16 screenColors     (&sd)   24-bit
analytics_debug.js:16 screenResolution (&sr)   1920x1080
analytics_debug.js:16 title            (&dt)   example
analytics_debug.js:16 trackingId       (&tid)  UA-XXXXX-Y
analytics_debug.js:16 viewportSize     (&vp)   1140x901
analytics_debug.js:16 Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)
(index):544 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):544)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):544
[...]
```

So I think the initial pageview is correctly tracked (I also see pageviews on the GA page), but the url changes are not tracked. Anyone who can help me make this work?

Comment: Found the solution. Had to do with the way I updated the url with shiny.

Comment: @dr-zins, can you explain what was the problem & how did you solve it. I also have a similar problem?